# converting string to float gives an error

Tags: c#

I want to convert a value from string to float in c#. the value definitely has precision(I mean .00 or .67 in this example. I don't know the word in English for sure) like "120.00" , "233.67"

and this is what I do for doing that

```
   float existingValue = float.Parse(param[1].ToString());
```

`param[1]` contains the string value

but gives me error :

> 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

If I change the value from "120.00" to "120" it works fine

what is the problem for that?

Comment: I assume in your current culture the `,` is the decimal separator instead of the `.`

Comment: Is it working if you parse `"120,00"` instead of `"120.00"`?

Comment: Sidenote: If `param[1]` is already a `string` then calling `param[1].ToString()` is pointless.

Comment: It's not as simple as it just being because '.' is the thousands separator in the current culture, because in that case it would parse to `12000`. It seems that the '.' is not being parsed as a decimal mark OR a thousands separator. I don't know what locale that would occur in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an overload of float.Parse method. Specify IFormatProvider as an argument (e. g. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture or a specifc one) or NumberStyles.